# Remove whitespace using regex in an expression

Tags: regex, stl

I'm looking for a regex to change something like

```
a = bb cc + 2 + (5 ^ 2 )
```

to

```
a=bb cc+2+(5^2)
```

(notice that b and c don't get smooshed together)

The idea being to remove whitespace around operators, but not between variables.

I'm trying to use stl with c++, so I would do:

```
std::wstring trimmed = std::regex_replace(resolvedExpression, 
    std::wregex(regexSolution), L"", std::regex_constants::match_default);
```

Comment: that won't work for other operators and brackets... guess I should clarify my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pattern like this:

```
s/\s*([+\-=*^%()?:<>+\/.,])\s*/\1/g
```

What this will do is match any operator surrounded by zero or more spaces on either side, then replace that entire string with just the operator in question. The `g` modifier makes it global (operating on the entire string, rather than just the first match).

[Demo on regexr](http://regexr.com/3ec8g)

Your code in C++, using the standard library, will look something like this:

```
std::wstring cleanExpression(std::wstring expression) {
    return std::regex_replace(
        expression,
        std::wregex(L"\\s*([+\\-=*^%()?:<>+/.,])\\s*"),
        L"$1"
    );
}
```

Note that this (quite obviously) requires a C++ compiler with proper support for `std::regex`, which was added to `gcc` in version 4.9.0. Not sure about other compilers, though.

Comment: throwing this into http://www.regexr.com/ doesn't produce the right result. thanks though

Comment: that works, thanks! I need to modify it a bit to remove spaces around more operators, so std::wregex(L"\\s*([+\\-=*^%()?:<>+/.,])\\s*")

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
\s*([+\-=*]+)\s*
```

https://regex101.com/r/oU39fi/1

Comment: that includes the operators in the search; I don't want to strip those out